# How to get the highest value of each date in a not finding MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

In this case, the problem I'm having is to make a distinction of a list taking all the values of each registered day. Example:

{car: "Volvo", km:"101", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-22T14:43:32.924+01:00")},

**{car: "Volvo", km:"105", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-22T14:50:32.924+01:00")},**

{car: "Volvo", km:"115", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-23T19:43:32.924+01:00")},

**{car: "Volvo", km:"119", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-23T20:30:32.924+01:00")},**

{car: "BMW", km:"40", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-10T14:43:32.924+01:00")},

{car: "BMW", km:"43", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-10T14:50:32.924+01:00")},

**{car: "BMW", km:"50", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-10T19:43:32.924+01:00")},**

**{car: "BMW", km:"59", dateInsert: : ISODate("2019-10-11T20:30:32.924+01:00")},**
...

In this case is on bold showing only I need the last record of each day.

Whats is good way to get this records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O7Vx3E7IS5Y)

MongoDB can compare documents also, by comparing the fields one by one, if they have same name, so putting `km` first field, we will get the `max` `km` first. `$$ROOT` is a system variable, has the value for all the document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "year": {
          "$year": "$dateInsert"
        },
        "day": {
          "$dayOfYear": "$dateInsert"
        }
      },
      "max": {
        "$max": {
          "km": "$km",
          "doc": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$max.doc"
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

- `$substr` and `$dateToString` to extract only the date from the `ISODate`.
- `$group` and `$addToSet` to group all documents by the unique date.
- `$reduce` to find the document with maximum value of `km` field for each date.
- `$project` to project the result with proper fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "dateInsert": {
        $substr: [
          {
            $dateToString: {
              date: "$dateInsert"
            }
          },
          0,
          10
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$dateInsert",
      "results": {
        $addToSet: {
          car: "$car",
          km: "$km"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "results": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$results",
          initialValue: {
            km: 0
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $gte: [
                  "$$this.km",
                  "$$value.km"
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      dateInsert: "$_id",
      car: "$results.car",
      km: "$results.km",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NkBxmdFT1_F